# UIImage animatedImageNamed repeat count

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a images sequence animated with :

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 120)];
[UIImage animatedImageNamed:@"spinner-" duration:1.0f];
imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
imgView.animationRepeatCount = 1; // No effect
[self.view addSubView:imgView];
```

But the sequence keeps looping. Is there a way to control the repeat count (and keep displaying the last image) ?

Comment: How are you displaying the image? UIImageView has a animationRepeatCount property, which may be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks but this seems to have no effect. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In your case, using `[UIImage animatedImageNamed:@"spinner-" duration:1.0f];` won't give you what you want.

For what you would like to achieve, I would recommend using `UIImageView`.

*Usage:*

First create an `UIImageView` object:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:<FRAME_SIZE>];
```

Second, create an array that holds your images to be animated.

If you just have a few, do the following:

```
NSMutableArray *animatedImagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"spinner-1.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"spinner-2.png"], nil];
```

If you have more, then you could load your images into the array like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < <NUM_OF_IMAGE_COUNT>; i++)
{
    [animatedImagesArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"spinner-%d%@", i, @".png"]]];
}
```

Once all that is done, then we configure the controls you want:

```
imageView.animationImages = animatedImagesArray;

imageView.animationDuration = 1.0f;

imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1.0f;
```

Then start animating it by:

```
[imageView startAnimating];
```

And stop the animation via:

```
[imageView stopAnimating];
```

If you would like the `UIImageView` to hold the last image after stopping, we would need to carry out the following *before* starting the animation:

```
imageView.image = [imageView.animationImages lastObject];
....

[imageView startAnimating];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice solution, but as a small optimisation, you can skip the for loop. You can get the animated image with `UIImage *image = [UIImage animatedImageNamed:@"spinner-" duration:1.0f];` and then use it's images and assign it to the image view with `imageView.animationImages = image.images;` You can then remove the for loop and you no longer need to keep track of the amount of images for each animation.

Answer (score 1):

You set the repeat count in the UIImageView object that displays your image.

```
UIImage *testImage = [UIImage animatedImageNamed:@"Box.jpg" duration:1.0f];
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:testImage];
[imgView setAnimationRepeatCount:1];
```

Comment: Thanks but this seems to have no effect. See my updated answer.